# Moving Windows 10 from old BIOS computer to new UEFI-only computer

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, uefi, system-reserved-partition

My customer is running Windows 10 on an ancient computer - so ancient it doesn't even support USB 3, but it is 64-bit.  It's some kind of Pentium-class machine that originally had Windows 7 on it.  Then he bought a shiny new Lenovo laptop that doesn't support legacy BIOS boot and wants me to clone the old system onto it.

I booted the old machine with Linux Mint and made an image of it with dd (took about six hours to do it over a USB 2.0 connection).  It consists of three partitions - System Reserved, the main data partition, and a WinRE recovery partition.  All of them are NTFS with MBR/DOS partitioning.  I then dd'd this image onto the new machine and, needless to say, it won't boot for love or money.  I've tried using mbr2gpt.exe on it but it won't pass validation.

At this point, I'm stuck.  I don't want to use third-party imaging software.  I'm thinking that I can manually partition the new computer's disk with GPT and then copy the data partition over, but what to do about the System Reserved partition?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: using `dd` for imaging is a bad idea. A disk imaging tool would be much better because they can skip empty sectors or files like pagefile.sys... and produce a far smaller image. On Linux there's clonezilla and on Windows there are things like Acronis True Image and the ancient Norton Ghost...

Comment: " I've tried using mbr2gpt.exe on it, but it won't pass validation." - Provide a screenshot of the partitions.  The requirements for MBR2GPT are very specific.  " I don't want to use third-party imaging software." - If you want to achieve your customer's goal this will be an almost certainty you will end up using third-party software to accomplish your task.

Comment: Just my opinion, but apart from licensing issues, cloning a Windows installation from an old computer to a newer computer is almost always a bad idea, as there is an endless list of potential problems to solve. For instance you will have on the one hand useless drivers installed, and on the other hand missing drivers. Fixable, but tedious. And if this is a brand new laptop it is under Windows 11? If yes it is very possible that Lenovo never validated Windows 10 on it.

Comment: You might try running the old Windows 10 disk on the new PC in a VM... That said, I do not know if thta would be feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the original OS on the old computer is OEM then you cannot move Windows 10 to a new computer.

The new Lenovo Computer comes with (most likely) Windows 11 (almost a year into the Windows 11 release).

So use the new computer as it is. try to recover data on the old disk by means of a disk carrier. Put the disk in the carrier and try to recover the data.

Trying to use the old install (OEM) is not going to work, both licensing and drivers. Possibly other issues will also get in the way, so truly best to start fresh.

You need to explain the above to the customer because they just may not be aware of the above realities and limitations.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with "CHIP SBIANCAMENTO" (ITALY):
-Boot from old PC(BIOS) with MBR/GPT Hard Disk schema
-Switch from different version of OS with same data
-Hardware failure diagnostic
-Repair in 5min computer without data loss
-Switch from bad hardware to another without reinstall system
-System reconstruction without data lose
-etc

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).